# How to set up Edimax ew-7811un on Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, setup, pi-zero, kali

I have spent hours reading articles and changing file after file over and over again. I am truing to properly set up my Edimax ew-7811un wifi adapter on m a Pi Zero running Kali Linux. I was able to set it up once upon a time when I had Jessie running on it. I remember that it was a pain setting it up back then and it's even worse now. I believe that I possibly used a bach file to set things up in the end.

My current situation is simple. My Pi sees the adapter, it even flashes blue. I've changed the /etc/network/interfaces and the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf (had to create it because it did not exist) multiple times. The network logo appears to be connected, but it does not connect to my network.

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid"NAME"
wpa-psk "NETWORK_PASSWORD"
```

I updated the Interfaces File multiple times and this is the latest rendition. I saw that many people resolved their issue by directly placing their network info into the interfaces file. I still ran into the same issue.

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant ctrl_interface_group=0 ap_scan=2
network={
        ssid="NAME"
        scan_ssid=1
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        group=CCMP
        psk="PASSWORD"
}
```

This is what the wpa_supplicant file looks like as of now. Even though it isn't being called it still exists as a file.

The adapter currently doesn't seem to work because of the changed interfaces file, but when it did "work" it wouldn't receive an IP address. I would have to run *sudo ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0* to enable it and get it to start blinking. It would also show that it was connected to my router but it would not connect to the internet.

There is not a single article that is specific to my issue (TBH, no article is always specific to one issue) but I really need to figure this out. I can never master something if i'm always getting stuck in the process. I don't like asking for help, but help. I'll provide as much information as possible. There are a lot of factors that go into this. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

After applying the changes that @Jason Woodruff I got the following:

```
spa_supplicant: /sbin/spa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlan0
```

UPDATE_4

[image]

Update_5 SOLUTION

Following Update 3 of the answer helped to solve my problem. Ensure that the hub is getting enough power and is able to scan for available wifi hotspots.

After confirming the connection on root and user profile you can then run sudo apt- update and sudo apt-get upgrade

After performing the upgrade and rebooting, you will get most if not all of the Kali tools.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a full listing of both your network/interfaces and wpa_supplicant.conf files? Also, it would be worth ruling out other issues - can the adapter connect to *other* networks? Have you tried, for example, connecting to a mobile phone hotspot?

Comment: @goobering I updated the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: It might sound stupid but have you got MAC filtering enabled in your Router?  I.e. even with a password it will deny access to WiFi devices that are not on its "approved" list - in this day and age it is not unreasonable to be a bit paranoid what devices you allow to connect to your Broadband (to prevent [WarDriving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardriving))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read on the Kali forums,  it's ARM version ships with an outdated driver for the Edimax EW-7811Un. Just for knowing, run this command:

```
lsmod
```

To see if you see something like:

```
8192cu
```

I'm just going out on a limb here, I think your dealing with an outdated driver for that wifi dongle. I believe you'll find more help over at the [forums](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?27443-Raspberry-Pi-RTL8188CUS-Wifi-dongle-Monitor-mode-issue&highlight=Edimax)

UPDATE:

If you will, try this:

Make the section for your wlan0 in /etc/network/interfaces look like this:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

In your wpa_supplicant.conf file, make it like this:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
               ssid="YOUR_SSID"
               psk="YOUR_PSK"
}
```

Good luck

Update 2:

Backup your current interfaces file

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces_old
```

Now make a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Copy and paste this in there:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8)  and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/ dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/   interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Change your ssid back, as it is actually spell. If there is uppercase letters in it, use the same. That goes for your password too. In your wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Reboot and test.

UPDATE 3:

We'll Pepe, I got my Edimax connected. It happened as root (only) and I only had to use the /etc/network/interfaces file. No wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Here is my file:

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp

 auto wlan0
 iface wlan0 inet dhcp
 wpa-ssid "my_router"
 wpa-psk "my_password"
```

It takes about a full two minutes to connect, but it does connect. Some kind of script runs that slows things down. I hope this helps. Other than mine being a RPi B, not zero, we have basically the same setup. The only thing I can think that could be hindering the connection is your router's encryption type. Epecially if it's an ols WEP kind.

Good Luck!

Update 4:

Add your username to the "sudo" group. To do that type this as root:

```
adduser pepe sudo
```

Make this part of the instructions.

Comment: When running lsmod, 8192cu does pop up. I believe my problem comes from the interfaces or wpa_supplicant.conf files. It seems that every article has a different way of writing the interfaces and wpa_supplicant files. I just need to know the write way of writing them for Kali on the Pi Zero.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to work. I updated my question to include what happened after replacing the text in the files.

Comment: What is the output of this command: tail -n300 /var/log/syslog | grep wlan0

Comment: Also, you do have a password for your router?

Comment: Yes I have a password for my router. When I run that command I get a whole lot of stuff. Last line states the following: Failed to bring up wlan0

Comment: I'm sorry I've not been too helpful, but when you run ifconfig, do you see a listing for wlan0, of course, I know you won't have an IP address. Is it there?

Comment: @JohnWoodruff You responded to my question, that's huge help. You're also not going to believe this, but wlan0 isn't appearing. Just lo. It was there last I checked. I'm very sorry if i'm coming off as a noob.

Comment: Tell me about your power to you pi? Sounds silly, but under powering the usb wifi dongle can cause problems. Is it atleast 2 amps? Your power adapter?

Comment: @JohnWoodruff Well at the moment of you asking that question, no the powered USB hub was running off of the Pi Zero. I just plugged it in. However, at the time of setting it up it was always plugged in to external power so power wouldn't be the issue. It's not silly because I have read in multiple places that power can cause an issue. I will ad that when running sudo lsusb THE pi recognizes the adapter. Also, just out of curiosity what time is it where you are at?

Comment: Just realized I said "John", sorry. If I run sudo iwconfig wlan0 does appear. Not sure if that's helpful.

Comment: I am in CST? 10:53pm

Comment: Okay. I ask because in my head im thinking its super late where you're at. I've been awake around 1AM trying to figure this out. It's almost midnight where I'm at. I hope my last comments were useful.

Comment: That's fine on the John thing. That's actually my uncles name. To stay on track here, when you run iwconfig, the wlan appears in ifconfig list?

Comment: When I run iwconfig, I see info about my wireless network I'm connected to.

Comment: wlan0 appears shows up if I run sudo iwconfig. wlan0 does NOT appear when I run sudo ifconfig. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Yes. May I ask, why are running that distro instead of Raspbian? If you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I didn't like Rasbian. It was great but I wanted something different. When I found out that Kali "works" on the pi zero I decided to give it a try. Kali is something that I want to get into a little more. I also love the xfce desktop. Xubuntu is actually my favorite distro. I updated the question to show a picture of what I get when running ifconfig and iwconfig.

Comment: One last request, unplug your wifi dongle, wait 30 seconds and re-plug it and run this command: dmesg | grep wlan0 , and please tell mewhat it says, especially anything that sounds negative.

Comment: Nothing shows up. It just runs and that's it. I just feel that it has to do with something in the interface and spa_supplicant.conf files. The adapter used to light up and listed on the broadcast address.

Comment: Ok, Iied, one more request, simply run dmesg, and tell me that last few lines. Btw, thank you for the screen shot.

Comment: That was a lot to take in. Everything looked fine except for something that said: failed to get irq for DAM channel 13 . Besides that everything looked good. It detected the edimax adapter and everything.

Comment: Ok, my mind is at ease on the hardware end of this. It's got to be in the configuration. The two files that are responsible for this, as you know are the /etc/network/interfaces file and the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. I would like to see those files in their enterity. Of corse, blank out the secure part. Can you screen shot that?

Comment: Also note, the wpa_supplicant file is very very particular. Any blank spaces at the end of the file can make the connection fail. In other words, you need to make sure there is no spaces at the end of the last "}".

Comment: Okay I updated the pictures, I think I had one space at the end so let me change that.

Comment: Bare with me, I will be updating my answer in a few moments.

Comment: Fingers crossed

Comment: Okay so I got the same issue. However, I changed the spa_supplicant file back to how I used to have it and now the adapter lights up. wlan0 appears in ifconfig but without an IP address. The logo in the upper right-hand corner changed but says that there is no network available. sudo apt-get update fails. So i'm still not technically connected.

Comment: Semi-positive here. So you have a gui there. You can use that to connect? If so, remove the ssid and the password from your wpa_supplicant.conf. btw, is that a typo when you say spa?

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a typo. Also, no I don't have a gui for connecting to wifi. If I don't have a GUI then I won't remove my password and SSID.

Comment: One thinng for sure Pepe, you have wlan0 showing back up in ifconfig. This is good. Now, run sudo iwconfig, tell me if you see your router?

Comment: No, my router does not appear here. Also, I think I found a gui for wifi. I'll upload a picture.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to see that.

Comment: Updated the post to include that picture. Let me know what I need to fill in. Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion before using that is to go and backup your wpa_supplicant.conf file and allow that gui to create one for you. Or just delete it by doing a sudo rm -i /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: Alright, I'll work on that tomorrow. I was currently trying ti set it up with a static IP. I thought it had worked but it tries to connect but still fails. I'll let you know tomorrow. Thanks again for all the help up till now. Get some sleep.

Comment: You to buddy. Thank you for letting me help. We'll figure it out!

Comment: Hello again, I have been trying to set up the WiFi network using the gui but I cannot get it to work. I've filled in the fields as best I can, but it doesn't let me save the configuration. Where can we go from here?

Comment: Here's my game plan. I've just downloaded Kali myself. I have the same Edimax wifi dongle like you. I'm going to be figuring this out. Unfortuantley, I'm due for work from 4pm to 12Am. That's where I was talking to you from last night. I won't be able to get my hands on this till after midnight. Maybe we can get back together then. I'm currently flashing my sd card now. By the time I get home, I can check this out. In the mean time, I'll be doing some forum checking. How about that?

Comment: Wow, great game plan. Don't mean to be a bother or interrupt you from work. I'll wait for you're response later tonight. I fell asleep at 3:30AM last night so im prepared. Which Pi do you have? Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: I have about 12 Rpi, no zeros, from Rpi B, B+, Rpi2 and 1 Rpi3. I will be using a B model for this, single core 700MHz, 512mb. We'll figure it out. Just bare with me. Thank you and I will be speaking to you later.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can connect on root, but I'm trying to connect on my user profile. On my user profile is fails to bring up wlan0 because the wpa_supplicany daemon failed to start. Why does it want wpa_supplicant.conf on my user profile but not on root?

Comment: Actually I take that back, it connected once and I erased my drive so I could set it up fresh and now it does DHCPSISCOVER on wlan0. Currently on root

Comment: Have you always been connecting before our conversation?

Comment: Well sort of. Sometimes the adapter would "see" my router (I think), but usually it would flat out not work. DHCPDISCOVER was something that I encountered a lot. Currently running the exact same setup as you (interface file, no wpa_supplicant).

Comment: I'm still struggling to get this resolved.

Comment: Have you added yourself to the sudoers list? I mean to the group "sudo"?

Comment: That's irrelevant at this point because I'm in root. I formatted my ad card. The problem in my user profile was that it wanted to access the wpa_supplicant.conf even though it didn't exist.

Comment: I'm not using wpa_supplicant. Once I set my wireless up with root, The network comes up everytime. Kali 4.1.19? I'm logged into it now, through SSH. As a regular user also.

Comment: I followed your instructions to the T. I'll reformat my drive again right now and do it over.

Comment: Update again to my answer

Comment: Oh I already knew that. But it's good to add it in so I can read through it and do it step by step. Thanks.

Comment: Although, this off topic, this has got to be a record for the longest unresolved post! LOL!!! And you like this distro all because of the Desktop?

Comment: I'll get in touch with The Guinness World Records. And you really want me to leave Kali for the Pi because you want this to be over lol.

Comment: Therefore I do that you for your continued help in this. I know this is an issue that I've seen in other places. We could have an entire tutorial in your answer.

Comment: I hate to say this Pepe, but I felt like I had did something wrong after visiting the Kali Linux website. I see it's about "white hat" hacking. It hasn't been easy. And although I can't claim to be a Linux guru, I have been a user for about 15 years now and this distro makes me feel like I'm starting all over again, lol.

Comment: Haha. Well it's software that's used for penetration testing. If I have certain server that I'm setting up I would want to hack the heck out of it to test its vulnerability. Kali using XFCE makes me feel at home. I feel like I'm starting over on any distro I use. Using Kali is completely legal but I can tell how it can some people feel.

Comment: Okay so I remortgaged my SD card and installed Kali again. Followed your instructions to the T and I get DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 etc. Then I get No DHCPOFFERS received . No working leases in persistent database - sleeping

Comment: What kind of security type do you use on that router? WPA, WPA2, , you know what I mean?

Comment: The security is WPA-PSK. Don't forget that I was able to connect once temporarily, I mentioned it in a previous comment.

Comment: I don't understand this at all, if it worked once but now it won't work at all. What is this DHCPDISCOVER and how can we resolve this?

Comment: Do this, sudo ps aux | grep network-manager (tell me if you see two lines listing this)

Comment: I'm not sure what "this" is referring to, but two lines do appear, I guess. It states it begins with root and ends with 0:00 Greco network-manager

Comment: Better yet, do, sudo service network-manager status (tell me if it's running)

Comment: Yes its active (running)

Comment: Try this, sudo service network-manager stop (try to sudo ifup wlan0)

Comment: I turned it off and attempted to do ifup wlan0 but it stated that it was already configured, so I did ifdown wlan0 and then ifup wlan0. After doing that it still does the DHCPDISCOVER but this time the network icon at the top shows that I'm not connected to anything

Comment: Do you have a eth0 that is or was connected to your router?

Comment: What does that mean? Do I have a different computer that is or was connected to my router via Ethernet?

Comment: On the pi zero, do you have a wired in ethernet on it. When you run sudo ifconfig, you don't see eth0 there, do you?

Comment: No, I do not have Ethernet on my Pi Zero. No eth0 appears, right now only lo and wlan0 appear

Comment: Btw, you can start network-manager with sudo service network-manager start

Comment: I'm going to ask this old question again. Please forgive me, but you are 100% sure you are typing in your ssid and password just as they are. No typos, right? 100% sure?

Comment: I do not care how many times you ask an old question, as long as it'll help us get this resolved, I'll gladly answer it. Let me check again.

Comment: It is 110% correct. I'll change it if it'll make it easier.

Comment: Could the issue lie with iface wlan0 obey dhcp ? I saw that other articles didn't have that sometimes. I believe.

Comment: I'll get with you on that. For right now, run this command, sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning (tell me if it list your router)

Comment: wlan0 No scan results

Comment: There you go, your wlan0 (edimax) adapter is not seeing your router. It can't nor want make a connection to something it cannot see. Of course, your next question is, why does it not see my router. The answer, I do not know. When I run this command, it sees all of wireless routers, including the ones it has never connected to. Your problem lies at the usb dongle. Run, sudo uname -a and tell me what you see?

Comment: TBH while I was reading your comment, I was expecting you to say something like "your on your own now" lol. I'll let you know what comes up

Comment: You're not going to believe this but it started working. The led on the single started lighting up after I switched ports and plugged in the power to the hub (I'll explain later) it got an IP and then it froze and the screen went dark. The Pi Zero led went solid as well as the dongle led. I restarted the Pi (USB power) and it started up but my keyboard didn't work. Had to restart it twice just to get it to work. Going to test the network momentarily and let you know if it's still "connected"

Comment: Cool, some power issues. I think we talked about that before. LOL. Good luck Pepe!

Comment: Yeah I know we talked about it before and I acknowledged it. The problem is, sometimes my keyboard and mouse would just not work and I would need to restart the Pi multiple times to force them to work. Just unplugged the job and they work so I left it unplugged. Booted the Pi back up and it seems like it wasn't connected to the Internet. Had to ifdown wlan0 and ifup wlan0 . Seems to connect now. So now I need to create my user profile

Comment: When creating the user I do usermod -a -G sudo user (This supposedly adds the user to the Sudo group) Is this alright or should I do something else? I also did chat -s /bin/bash user

Comment: That sounds great. Let me suggest, a logitech k400 is a all-in-one keyboard and mouse. Love it. It's great for this kind of stuff. I myself, I disabled the desktop and just use command line on my Kali Pi.

Comment: I just do a sudo adduser <name> then it has you to set the password.

Comment: So I should do sudo adduser user (even though I already do the other command?)

Comment: I take that back, after adduser, you need to do sudo passwd <user>

Comment: Yeah I already did that when I was initially creating the user.

Comment: Did it make the account, try to logon for a test

Comment: Logged in and apparently the interfaces file copied over my info from root. Had to do ifdown and ifup but it's working? I honestly don't understand. I'm going to pull the dongle out and stick it back in just to make sure.

Comment: To get the wlan0 connected, you have to ifdown and ifup it everytime?

Comment: Yes but that is the least of my worries. Currently trying to get my keyboard and mouse to work again. This is my 8 restart. Connecting the keyboard directly to the Pi works so it's an issue with the hub, I'll let you know momentarily once I get it to work.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm just glad you have narrowed this down to what was the problem.

Comment: So after a dozen more restarts and unplugging the hub another dozen times it started doing the DHCPDISCOVER thing again. However, the dongle was in another port this time, after switching it back to the only pot that I know worked with it, it started flashing again. An ifdown and ifup and BAM. IP! So I guess I've sort of narrowed it down. However, you provided the interfaces file that helped. So I'll mark your answer as answered!

Comment: FINALLY!!! LoL, I'm proud.

Comment: Doing my first update and upgrade, once it finishes I''ll mark it complete.

Comment: I'm assuming you are going to try and get another usb hub for your pi zero. Please keep me informed about any improvements. Have a good one!

Comment: Maybe. As a fellow human I get lazy if I can get it to work sometimes. I'm sitting here watching sudo apt-get upgrade run and I'm just waiting for it to finish so I can restart it. Huge thanks for everything. Hope to see you around the forum (just not like this again lol). Do you by any chance have a PayPal account so I could send you a small tip. It's the least I could do for ALL of your help.

Comment: Hey I'm glad I could help. In reality, you were the one that figured it out. Yeah, I'm sure you'll see me around here. Forget about the PayPal. In a week or so, I will be releasing a howto on project I've worked on. Not to go in detail, but it involves a Rpi2 installed in your vehicle, bluetoothed to your car radio, and you can have your favorite music tracks play from pi to your car radio, via bluetooth. You can actually control the mp3 player on the pi with the next song buttons on your stirring wheel, of your car. Currently testing it now. I will send you a link so you can check it out.

Comment: Alright then. Looking forward to seeing that project. Thanks again. Have a goodnight :)